# How to modify / rename the database name in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to modify / rename the database name in SQL?

Running the below script throws exception as " Incorrect syntax near @dbname "

```
Declare @dbname nvarchar(50)
set @dbname = 'MyDatabase_Test'

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase MODIFY NAME = @dbname;
```

Comment: Pretty sure you are going to need to go SINGLE_USER for this... and use Dynamic SQL...and hopefully QUOTENAME... but this just smells bad

Comment: I am working on automating the database restoration and keep the current database by renaming their name. I will have to do so periodically

Comment: Ugh that sounds like a really bad approach to this. Your database file names are going to be a nightmare to manage like that. Would be a lot simpler (and safer) to backup and restore to a different name instead of renaming the database. But needing to keep a copy of a database has a really bad code smell to it.

Comment: I have to follow this approach for the test environment to rename the existing database .. and restore the database with a new copy taken from another env

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @OldDbName nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @NewDbName nvarchar(100);

SET @OldDbName =  'MyTestDatabase';
SET @NewDbName =  'MyNewTestDatabase';
BEGIN TRY

        SET @SQLString =  
                    N'ALTER DATABASE ' +  @OldDbName + ' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK 
IMMEDIATE'; 
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString

        SET @SQLString =  
                    N'ALTER DATABASE ' +  @OldDbName + ' MODIFY NAME = ' + @NewDbName;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString            

        SET @SQLString =  
                    N'ALTER DATABASE ' +  @NewDbName + ' SET MULTI_USER' ;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this as dynamic SQL.

```
Declare @dbname nvarchar(50)
set @dbname = 'MyDatabase_Test'

EXEC('ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase MODIFY NAME = ' + @dbname);
```

Comment: Thanks.. but i am getting the error as Msg 5030, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.

Comment: @goofyui See scsimon's comment on your question.

Comment: I just need the syntax..for single_user